# Qt "passthrough" or "container" widget

Tags: reactjs, qt, design-patterns, pyside2

In Qt / PySide2, is there such a thing as a Qt widget that simply passes through to a wrapped widget, without adding any extra layers of layout etc.

I'm coming from a web frontend background, so my mental model is of a React [container component](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) that adds some behavior but then simply renders a wrapped presentational component.

However, there doesn't seem to be a way of doing this sort of thing in Qt without at least creating a layout in the wrapping widget, even if that layout only contains one widget. I could see that this could lead to multiple layers of redundant layout, which could be inefficient.

I acknowledge that it may be better to not try to replicate React patterns in Qt, so any suggestions of equivalent but more idiomatic patterns would also be welcome.

Comment: Sounds like a clear case of premature optimisation. What actual evidence do you have that adding layouts is inefficient? Worrying about implementation details like this is pointless if you haven't written any code.

Comment: It's not just about optimization. I have found that adding extra layers of layouts also appears to increase the amount of padding inside widgets (although there may be a styling fix for this).

Comment: It isn't about optimisation at all. And the [contents margins](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#setContentsMargins) can be adjusted easily enough. Like it or not, layouts are a fundamental part of Qt, so I suggest you learn how to use them properly. If you have a genuine problem that you don't know how to solve, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Added 2 example approaches to my answer, to expand on the previous comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I have to ask, what is the point of creating a container widget to just hold one widget, with no extra padding, layouts, or other "overhead?"  Why not just show the widget which would be contained?

Second, nothing says you must have a `QLayout` inside a `QWidget`. The layout simply moves any contained widgets around using `QWidget::setGeometry()` (or similar) on the child widget(s). It's trivial to implement a `QWidget` which sizes a child widget to match its own size, though it's fairly pointless because that's what `QLayout` is for. But I have included such an example below (C++, sorry)

A top-level `QLayout` set on a `QWidget` has default content margins (padding around the contained widget(s)). This can easily be removed with [`QLayout::setContentMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#setContentsMargins) (as mentioned in a previous comment).

"No-layout" "passthrough" `QWidget`:

```cpp
#include <QWidget>
class PassthroughWidget : public QWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT
  public:
    PassthroughWidget(QWidget *child, QWidget *parent = nullptr) :
      QWidget(parent),
      m_child(child)
    {
      if (m_child)
        m_child->setParent(this);  // assume ownership
    }

  protected:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *e) override
    {
      QWidget::resizeEvent(e);
      if (m_child)
        m_child->setGeometry(contentsRect());  // match child widget to content area
    }

    QWidget *m_child;  // Actually I'd make it a QPointer<QWidget> but that's another matter.
}
```

---

*ADDED*: To expand on my comments regarding *being* a widget vs. *having* (or managing) widget(s).

I just happen to be working on a utility app which makes use of both paradigms for a couple of parts. I'm not going to include all the code, but hopefully enough to get the point across. See screenshot below for how they're used. (The app is for testing some painting and transform code I'm doing, quite similar to (and started life as) the [Transformations Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-painting-transformations-example.html) in Qt docs.)

*What* the code parts below actually do isn't important, the point is *how* they're implemented, again specifically meant to illustrate the different approaches to a "controller" for visual elements.

First example is of something *being* a widget, that is, inheriting from `QWidget` (or `QFrame` in this case) and using other widgets to present a "unified" UI and API. This is an editor for two `double` values, like for a size width/height or coordinate x/y value. The two values can be linked so changing one will also change the other to match.

```cpp
class ValuePairEditor : public QFrame
{
    Q_OBJECT
  public:
    typedef QPair<qreal, qreal> ValuePair;

    explicit ValuePairEditor(QWidget *p = nullptr) :
      QFrame(p)
    {
      setFrameStyle(QFrame::NoFrame | QFrame::Plain);
      QHBoxLayout *lo = new QHBoxLayout(this);
      lo->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
      lo->setSpacing(2);

      valueSb[0] = new QDoubleSpinBox(this);
      ...
      connect(valueSb[0], QOverload<double>::of(&QDoubleSpinBox::valueChanged), 
        this, &ValuePairEditor::onValueChanged);
      // ... also set up the 2nd spin box for valueSb[1]

      linkBtn = new QToolButton(this);
      linkBtn->setCheckable(true);
      ....
      lo->addWidget(valueSb[0], 1);
      lo->addWidget(linkBtn);
      lo->addWidget(valueSb[1], 1);
    }

    inline ValuePair value() const 
      { return { valueSb[0]->value(), valueSb[1]->value() }; }

  public slots:
    inline void setValue(qreal value1, qreal value2) const
    {
      for (int i=0; i < 2; ++i) {
        QSignalBlocker blocker(valueSb[i]);
        valueSb[i]->setValue(!i ? value1 : value2);
      }
      emit valueChanged(valueSb[0]->value(), valueSb[1]->value());
    }

    inline void setValue(const ValuePair &value) const 
      { setValue(value.first, value.second); }

  signals:
    void valueChanged(qreal value1, qreal value2) const;

  private slots:
    void onValueChanged(double val) const {
      ...
      emit valueChanged(valueSb[0]->value(), valueSb[1]->value());
    }

  private:
    QDoubleSpinBox *valueSb[2];
    QToolButton *linkBtn;
};
```

Now for the other example, using a "controller" `QObject` which manages a set of widgets, but doesn't itself display anything. The widgets are available to the managing application to place as needed, while the controller provides a unified API for interacting with the widgets & data. Controllers can be created or destroyed as needed.

This example manages a `QWidget` which is a "render area" for doing some custom painting, and a "settings" `QWidget` which changes properties in the render area. The settings widget has further sub-widgets, but these are not directly exposed to the controlling application. In fact it also makes use of `ValuePairEditor` from above.

```cpp
class RenderSet : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
  public:
    RenderSet(QObject *p = nullptr) : 
      QObject(p),
      area(new RenderArea()),
      options(new QWidget())
    {
      // "private" widgets
      typeCb = new QComboBox(options);
      txParamEdit = new ValuePairEditor(options);
      ...
      QHBoxLayout *ctrLo = new QHBoxLayout(options);
      ctrLo->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
      ctrLo->addWidget(typeCb, 2);
      ctrLo->addWidget(txParamEdit, 1);
      ctrLo->addLayout(btnLo);

      connect(txParamEdit, SIGNAL(valueChanged(qreal,qreal)), this, SIGNAL(txChanged()));
    }

    ~RenderSet() override
    {
      if (options)
        options->deleteLater();
      if (area)
        area->deleteLater();
    }

    inline RenderArea *renderArea() const { return area.data(); }
    inline QWidget *optionsWidget() const { return options.data(); }

    inline Operation txOperation() const 
      { return Operation({txType(), txParams()}); }
    inline TxType txType() const 
      { return (typeCb ? TxType(typeCb->currentData().toInt()) : NoTransform); }
    inline QPointF txParams() const 
      { return txParamEdit ? txParamEdit->valueAsPoint() : QPointF(); }

  public slots:
    void updateRender(const QSize &bounds, const QPainterPath &path) const {
      if (area)
        ...
    }

    void updateOperations(QList<Operation> &operations) const {
      operations.append(txOperation());
      if (area)
        ...
    }

  signals:
    void txChanged() const;

  private:
    QPointer<RenderArea> area;
    QPointer<QWidget> options;
    QPointer<QComboBox> typeCb;
    QPointer<ValuePairEditor> txParamEdit;
};
```

[image]

Comment: "what is the point of creating a container widget to just hold one widget": So, I'm trying to recreate a pattern in react, where you the wrapping "component" (i.e. widget) can add behavior to the wrapped component, even the contained component is the only thing actually rendered. In React, this distinction is between "container" and "presentational" components. A presentational component is similar to a "passive view", I suppose. Obviously, React patterns may not be appropriate in this context, but in that case I was hoping to get some hints about the appropriate equivalent Qt idioms.

Comment: @samfrances Yea, sorry, I didn't read that React article much past where the author doesn't recommend it anymore. :)   I'm still not sure I see the point. if the "container" doesn't actually display anything then it probably should't _be_ a `QWidget`. It could _have_ a widget, or it could be assigned a widget to manage, but there's no point in it _being_ a widget unless it's going to add design elements. If it does need to paint/draw something which helps the "presentation" part (like a `QFrame` being able to add a visual border) then it makes sense for the container to _be_ a widget.

Comment: The nearest equivalent concept in Qt would be the distinction between a model (data container) and a view (presentational widget) - see the Qt docs article [Model/View Programming](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html). The relationship between widgets and layouts is completely different. Layouts are purely presentational components which manage the relative geometry of widgets. They do not contain data or provide any additional functionality - see the Qt docs article [Layout Management](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html).

Comment: Qt does not have a generic container component that can be used with all widgets. Instead, it prefers to use single inheritance to add extra functionality to base classes. For example, QPushButton, QCheckBox, QRadioButton, etc all inherit from QAbstractButton. It also makes heavy use of virtual and protected methods which can be overidden or reimplemented in user-defined subclasses of the built-in Qt classes - see the Qt docs article [Designing the User Interface](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tutorials-addressbook-part1-example.html).

Comment: `QWidget` _is_ the "generic container" in Qt C++ for visual presentation (Graphics Framework aside but even that needs to QWidget "container" to actually display something). As evidenced by the fact that every other widget inherits from it. If that's not generic enough, I don't know what is.

Comment: @MaximPaperno QWidget is a purely presentational component. It is not a container component in the sense given in the React article. There is nothing exactly like that in Qt, because it's simply not needed.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of managing widgets in Qt: by layouts or by parentness. Have you tried to use the `'parent'` approach?

[Docs says:](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/objecttrees.html)

`...The base class of everything that appears on the screen, extends the parent-child relationship. A child normally also becomes a child widget, i.e. it is displayed in its parent's coordinate system and is graphically clipped by its parent's boundaries.`

So, basically, if you use `setParent` for containing widgets, no layouts need to be created.

Comment: That doesn't appear to work. The wrapped widget simply doesn't get shown at all.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [QFrame](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qframe.html) in a similar manner, with all properties set to 0 and `Shape` set to `QFrame::NoFrame`. It is very useful as a dumb container for the actual widgets that end up doing the heavy lifting, `QStackedWidget` is one user of this. Quote from the docs:

> The QFrame class can also be used directly for creating simple placeholder frames without any contents.

However, I'm not sure it is 100% what you are looking for, as I'm not familiar with the React method you are outlining. Also not sure how far you can reasonably get without using layouts.

Comment: Isn't a `QFrame` with no actual frame then just a plain `QWidget` with useless properties? It would still need a layout or some way to manage any children.

Comment: True, you can't shy away from using layouts for anything usable/scalable. Though if you really want to have some kind of logical separation between just a frame (Container in OP's terminology) and actual widgets (Presentational) that's what I would use. However, arguably this would be better achieved by a different kind of design paradigm more suited to the framework and C++ world.

Comment: The QFrame class inherits QWidget, so there is no logical separation between them. They are both designed to "contain" other widgets in a purely presentational way. They aren't container components at all (in the React sense), and neither are any of the layout classes (which are also purely presentational). In React, container components contain only data, state and other abstract functionality - in Qt terms, they're somewhat like models (as opposed to views).