# Is it possible to use QT / LIBUI in React.JS style?

Tags: reactjs, qt, user-interface, qt5

One of advantage of React.JS is that you don't care about mutating one UI into another, magical React DIFF algorithm takes care of that.

You define what you want UI (one way `model -> UI` flow), and the magical React DIFF algorithm takes care transforming the current UI into the desired one. With other UI libraries usually you need to handle that manually and write lots of boring code how to transform current UI into new UI in reaction to some event or change.

**Is it possible to use QT5/LIBUI in a similar way?** I guess we can call it reactive UI style, maybe not exactly like React.JS but like Vue.JS or svelte.js, Elm etc.

Comment: You question is not clear, but if you are talking about data binding, QML aka Qt Quick module is doing it pretty nice. IMHO, you cannot compare these two techs. But as I worked with React, Angular and Qt for UI creation, I always prefer Qt for anything, anywhere if it's possible.

Comment: @SoheilArmin it's larger than the data binding. If I update the model let's say `model.isEditFieldVisible = true` the UI should be updated automatically in all the places that use or rely on the variable `isEditFieldVisible`.

Comment: Ok. what you are describing is ***exactly*** data binding which is nicely supported by Qt.

Comment: Are we talking about C++ or QML UI? (And what is "LIBUI?") Besides the QML property bindings already described, there's a "State Machine" framework which can transition between UI states. There's a [C++ version](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/statemachine-api.html) as well as [QML side](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmlstatemachine.html). Funny, there was just another React JS [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58520625/qt-passthrough-or-container-widget/58654892#58654892)... is this a movement?  :)

Comment: @MaximPaperno hmm, I'm from Web Dev and don't know much about QT (what's QML). I'm looking for any way to use QT or other UI library in a way similar to React.JS.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is yes. But in regard to Qt5, it's much more robust and well structured. It's not a good decision to compare these two techs. I'm a Qt enthusiast, so I may give you biased opinion.

Here is some explanation about [Qt Property Binding](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-propertybinding.html).

Quote from that page:

> **Property Binding**
>
> An object's property can be assigned a static value
> which stays constant until it is explicitly assigned a new value.
> However, to make the fullest use of QML and its built-in support for
> dynamic object behaviors, most QML objects use property bindings.
>
> Property bindings are a core feature of QML that lets developers
> specify relationships between different object properties. When a
> property's dependencies change in value, the property is automatically
> updated according to the specified relationship.
>
> Behind the scenes, the QML engine monitors the property's dependencies
> (that is, the variables in the binding expression). When a change is
> detected, the QML engine re-evaluates the binding expression and
> applies the new result to the property.